# Why is this 1 image showing an infinite number of times?

Tags: php, database, image, oop, mysqli

```
$pgroup = $Sys->db->query("SELECT dj_photo_group.photo_group, dj_photo.name FROM dj_photo_group, dj_photo WHERE dj_photo_group.photo_group = dj_photo.img_group ORDER BY dj_photo.img_group DESC");

while($photo = $pgroup->fetch_object()) {

    echo '<div class="photo_head">' . ucfirst($photo->photo_group) . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="photo_sub">';

    while($photo->name) {
        echo '<img src="photogallery/' . $photo->photo_group . '/' . $photo->name . '" />';
    }

    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

This is showing the same 1 image over and over again. I have 3 groups: Wedding, 5points and Misc that have 2 images each. It only shows Weddings with 1 image infinite number of times.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because `$photo->name` is always true so you are never going out of the 2nd while loop, that's called an infinite loop

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this.. this solution will provide you your desired layout....

```
$pgroup1 = $Sys->db->query("SELECT dj_photo_group FROM photo_group GROUP BY dj_photo_group");

while ($photo1 = $pgroup1->fetch_object())
{

echo '<div class="photo_head">' . ucfirst($photo1->dj_photo_group) . '</div>';
echo '<div class="photo_sub">';
$pgroup2 = $Sys->db->query("SELECT name FROM dj_photo WHERE img_group = '$photo1->dj_photo_group'");

while ($photo2 = $pgroup2->fetch_object())
{
    echo '<img src="photogallery/' . $photo1->dj_photo_group . '/' . $photo2->name . '" />';
}

echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. The if is still giving me the same result. Weddings -> 2 images, 5points -> 2 images and Misc -> 2 images. It is putting each image in a separate div. The Wedding, 5points and Misc has 2 images each I am getting 6 divs with 1 image in each I should have 3 divs (wedding, 5points and misc) with 2 images displayed in each of the 3 divs. Hopefully I have explained a little better. This is driving me up the wall XD. Thanks all.

Comment: Some how I need to get 1 group (Weddings) then cycle through the image names in that group then once that is done i need to go to the next group (5points) and display the 2 images in that div and so on.

Comment: ohh ok.. I got it.. please check my edited answer... @user3377300

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nishant. This solution is less querying to the database if anyone else runs into this problem the solution is at http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=139334&p=691638#p691638 Thanks everyone for your help!!!

Comment: click the link :p it works exactly how I wanted it to

Comment: @user3377300 he he.. super... enjoy.. and if you dont mind than please +1 my answer.. some moron has downvoted my ans...

Answer (score 0):

`$photo->name` is always true. So if you use it in a while loop, you're essentially saying:

```
while(true){
    // do this
}
```

Remember, while loops will keep going as long as the condition specified is true.

You should really be using an `if` statement instead.

```
if($photo->name){
    // do this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`while($photo->name)` will repeat until `$photo->name` is false. Because in the loop there is nothing that will change it, it will always be true, and so the loop continues forever.

Like Nishant said, you want to replace it with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

**while($photo->name)**  is entering into infinite loop as the condition is always true. You should put an end condition to this while loop or otherwise you can go for if condition also

```
if($photo->name)
```